# How to resolve a namespace on php?

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm doing the first test on php5. More specifically I'm trying to work with namespaces but it seems that php is not resolving the namespace. Here the test I've done:

file 1: test.php

```
<?
namespace \first_test;

class Test  {
    function test_function(){
        print "works";
    }
}
?>
```

file 2: use_namespace.php

```
<?
use \first_test;


$a=new \first_test\Test();
$a->test_function();
?>
```

I get a fatal error: 
Fatal error: Class 'first_test\Test' not found in 
here_the_path_where use_namespace.php is.

Any help appreciated.

P.S. Both files are on the same directory, php 5.3.9 on windows.

Comment: shouldn't you include the file anyway?

Comment: @yes123, read my comment below. There I comment why I guess 
I have not to include the file.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `\` when declaring a namespace, you only need it when calling functions from it.

```
<?php
   namespace first_test;

  // ...
?>
```

Also, in your 2nd file, you need to `include test.php`, otherwise it doesn't know what `first_test` is.

Comment: also if you do `use first_test;` you can instanciate your class without the namespace : `$a = new Test;`

Comment: Hi @Rocket. As I said this is a test. The target is to use a 3rd-party library which uses namespaces. As It didn't work i created a small set test. As far as I know I've not to include test.php, importing with **use** should be enought. Indeed on the library, are several files and no one includes anyone else, only declaring namespaces and importing them throught **use** keyword. So I guess could be something related with php configuration which doesn't allow to detect the namespaces? I've checked the value of include_path and the directory where those phps are is included on it. Any idea? thx.

Comment: @xtarafa: I don't really know how namespaces work, that was just the 1st thing I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

In the 3rd-party library they most likely use autoloader, which automaticly does all the required includes. So if you dont want to manually write include, add your own autoloader
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

It is a general aproach that you entry point contains autoloader, so all included files will use it automaticly. Description of coding standart for this can be found at https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/